# How to deploy empty directories to tomcat with maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-3, pom.xml

I am working on a web project with **REST** web services. I use `maven 3.0.4` and eclipse Juno and I am deploying my project to tomcat installation directory using the goals `-e clean:clean tomcat:redeploy`

The problem is that when I create an empty directory into the webapp folder and I try to deploy it to tomcat then the empty directory is not included into the **.war** file.

How can I force maven to include empty directories to the **.war** build?

I tried adding the code below to my **pom.xml** but it didn't work

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ba</groupId>
    <artifactId>Oasis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF JAX-RS webapp service using spring configuration</name>
    <description>Simple CXF JAX-RS webapp service using spring configuration</description>

    <dependencies>
                 ...
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>myserver</server>
                    <url>http://localhost:9090/manager/html</url>
                    <path>/oasis</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks